# Django: for loop and POST request create function

Tags: python, json, django

In the project there is a model with existing instances in the database.

```
class Instagram(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

There is another model, so far without instaces

```
class InstagramAgesAnalitics(models.Model):    
    instagram = models.ForeignKey(Instagram)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=10)    
    viewer_percentage = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Now I need from the values ​​stored in the json file, create new instances of the InstagramDemographicsAnalitics model. For this, I wrote a function that uses the for loop and substitutes the required key values ​​in the instance fields.

**example.json**

```
{
    "@nightcrvwlxr": {                              
        "userId": "5697152",                
        "content_persons_statistic": {
            "ages": {
                "45-64": 0.016358024691358025,
                "18-24": 0.37570950015055704,
                "25-34": 0.2789897621198434,
                "13-17": 0.2103470340258958,
                "35-44": 0.11859567901234568
            },                      
            "genders": {
                "MALE": 0.6046939714680166,
                "FEMALE": 0.39530602853198343
            }
        }           

    }
}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import InstagramDemographicsAnalitics, Instagram, InstagramAgesAnalitics

def get_ida_instance(request):

    with open('/home/jekson/projects/jsontest/example.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        for key, value in data.items():
            print(value['userId'])
            instagram = Instagram.objects.get(userid=value['userId'])
            ages = (value["content_persons_statistic"]['ages'])
            for key, value in ages.items():
                ida = InstagramAgesAnalitics()
                ida.instagram = instagram
                ida.age_group = key
                ida.viewer_percentage = float(str(value))
                ida.save()
                print(key + ":" + " " + str(value))
                return HttpResponse("Succesful")

    return render(request, 'ida.html')
```

template.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit">Click Me!</button>
```

When I click the Сleck Me button, I get Successful, but only one instance of the model appears in the database. But I expect the appearance of four on the basis of this data:

```
"45-64": 0.016358024691358025,
"18-24": 0.37570950015055704,
"25-34": 0.2789897621198434,
"13-17": 0.2103470340258958,
"35-44": 0.11859567901234568
```

If replace the code for creating instances with ***print (key + ":" + "" + str (value))*** in the **get_ida_instance** function, then in the console I see all the values ​​I need. Why are not the remaining instances created?

Answer (score 4):

You return inside the inner loop, so it can only ever execute one time. Move that return statement back two indent levels.

Comment: Such a big question, such a simple solution. Thank you!